# Cant get SpatialReference to work(ArcGIS)

Tags: android, arcgis

ive been trying to get SpatialReference to work in ArcGIS and no matter what i try i cant get it to work, any help is appreciated.
here is my code

```
wgs84 = SpatialReference.create(SpatialReference.WKID_WGS84);


    SimpleMarkerSymbol simpleMarker = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.RED, 5,SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE.CIRCLE);


    Point pointGeometry = new Point(-35.238019 ,149.083404,0,SpatialReference.WKID_WGS84);
   /* Point pointGeometry = new Point(16596066.8,-3896170.7);*/

    Graphic pointGraphic = new Graphic(pointGeometry, simpleMarker);


    mGraphicsLayer.addGraphic(pointGraphic);
```

Comment: longitude (x), then latitude (y).... you have them a-backward

Comment: ps.  you really should be looking here for answers https://geonet.esri.com/welcome there are sections by language and api

Comment: my problem is that is not using WKID._WGS84 and uses whatever the default is

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. **Specify coordinates in the correct order.** Whenever you specify coordinates, you need to check the ArcGIS Runtime documentation ([10.2.x](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference), [Quartz](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/beta/api-reference)) to see which order to use. When you create a `Point`, you specify X (longitude) first, then Y (latitude). 149.083404 is not a valid latitude, so I assume you mean it to be longitude. Switch them around.
2. **Unless the documentation says "longitude" and "latitude," assume map coordinates.** That means you need to project your point to the map's spatial reference using `GeometryEngine.project`, unless you call a method whose parameters are `longitude` and `latitude` instead of `x` and `y`.

I can't tell whether you're using 10.2.x or Quartz Beta--you're using elements from each--so here's a working example using each API.

Quartz (assumes you have declared a `MapView` in the layout XML):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mMapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        // ArcGISMap constructor takes latitude (Y) first
        ArcGISMap map = new ArcGISMap(Basemap.Type.TOPOGRAPHIC,
                -35.238019, 149.083404, 10);
        mMapView.setMap(map);

        GraphicsOverlay graphicsLayer= new GraphicsOverlay();
        mMapView.getGraphicsOverlays().add(graphicsLayer);

        SimpleMarkerSymbol simpleMarker = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
                SimpleMarkerSymbol.Style.CIRCLE, Color.RED, 5);
        // Point constructor takes X (longitude) first
        Point pointGeometry = new Point(
                149.083404, -35.238019, 0, SpatialReference.create(4326));
        Graphic pointGraphic = new Graphic(pointGeometry, simpleMarker);
        graphicsLayer.getGraphics().add(pointGraphic);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        mMapView.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.resume();
    }
}
```

10.2.x (assumes you have declared a `MapView` with `MapOptions` in the layout XML file):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mMapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        mMapView.setOnStatusChangedListener(new OnStatusChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(Object o, STATUS status) {
                if (STATUS.INITIALIZED.equals(status)) {
                    // MapOptions constructor takes latitude (Y) first
                    MapOptions mapOptions = new MapOptions(
                            MapOptions.MapType.TOPO, -35.238019, 149.083404, 10);
                    mMapView.setMapOptions(mapOptions);

                    GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
                    mMapView.addLayer(graphicsLayer);

                    SimpleMarkerSymbol simpleMarker = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
                            Color.RED, 5, SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE.CIRCLE);
                    // GeometryEngine.project takes X (longitude) first
                    Point pointGeometry = GeometryEngine.project(
                            149.083404, -35.238019, mMapView.getSpatialReference());
                    Graphic pointGraphic = new Graphic(pointGeometry, simpleMarker);
                    graphicsLayer.addGraphic(pointGraphic);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        mMapView.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.unpause();
    }
}
```